# How to extend or modify ESLint rule rather than overwrite

Tags: angular, eslint

I have an Angular project that uses ESLint. I want to modify the `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` rule to add an exception to stop it linting certain property names on objects used in external APIs. For example, the Google Analytics `gtag` has a property in snake case which doesn't fit with the rest of the applications camel case style but I don't want it to be flagged.

```
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX', {
  page_path: event.urlAfterRedirects
})
```

How can I keep the rules as they are but just add this exception? The `naming-convention` rule is quite complicated and I don't want to completely overwrite it because it is useful to be able to keep up to date with any changes that reflect changes to the Angular project. My ESLint config extends the following:

```
"extends": [
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [doc](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md), the default config for the `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` rule is the following.

```
// the default config is similar to ESLint's camelcase rule but more strict
const defaultOptions: Options = [
  {
    selector: 'default',
    format: ['camelCase'],
    leadingUnderscore: 'allow',
    trailingUnderscore: 'allow',
  },

  {
    selector: 'variable',
    format: ['camelCase', 'UPPER_CASE'],
    leadingUnderscore: 'allow',
    trailingUnderscore: 'allow',
  },

  {
    selector: 'typeLike',
    format: ['PascalCase'],
  },
];
```

Therefore, I would say that you should copy that config and amend it with your changes.